# Entity Framework cannot add foreign key on inherited columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, foreign-keys

I am using EF 6.2.

I have an abstract base class, let's call it `Person`, which some classes inherit from, let's say `Student` and `Teacher`. Each person can have two addresses. This gives something like that:

```
public abstract class Person
{
    ...
    public int LocationAddressId { get; set; }
    public Address LocationAddress { get; set; }

    public int ContactAddressId { get; set; }
    public Address ContactAddress { get; set; }
}

[Table("Student")]
public class Student : Person
{ ... }

[Table("Teacher")]
public class Teacher : Person
{ ... }
```

This works as expected. So I tried to add the reverse navigation property to Address:

```
public class Address
{
    [InverseProperty(nameof(Person.LocationAddress))]
    public ICollection<Person> LocationAddresses { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Person.ContactAddress))]
    public ICollection<Person> ContactAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

But this throws

> SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Person'

So instead I tried:

```
public class Address
{
    [InverseProperty(nameof(Student.LocationAddress))]
    public ICollection<Student> StudentLocationAddresses { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Student.ContactAddress))]
    public ICollection<Student> StudentContactAddresses { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Teacher.LocationAddress))]
    public ICollection<Teacher> TeacherLocationAddresses { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Teacher.ContactAddress))]
    public ICollection<Teacher> TeacherContactAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

This time it throws

> ModelValidationException: NavigationProperty 'LocationAddress' is not valid. Type 'Student' of FromRole 'Address_StudentLocationAddresses_Target' in AssociationType 'Address_StudentLocationAddresses' must exactly match with the type 'Teacher' on which this NavigationProperty is declared on.

Seems EF has a problem to reuse an inherited property by multiple foreign keys... or what am I doing wrong? How can I add this navigation property? Please note that I need to have at least an abstract definition of the address relations in Person (everything else would lead to a lot of duplicated code) and I prefer attributes over the fluent api.